# How can I find occurrences of German umlaut characters in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, diacritics

I have a sheet with names like:

```
Jürgen
Fabian
```

The first record has an umlaut character (ä ö ü ß Ä Ö Ü). So I need a way to "flag" this occurrence. A "yes" next to the name (in a new column) would be nice.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A1:A), "ä|ö|ü|ß"), "yes", ))
```

[image: 0]